# heavy query MySQL explanation

Tags: mysql

I'd like to understand what this query does.

Can anyone explain to me in words, the meaning of the following query?

```
http://www.kachakil.com/pista.aspx?id_pista=1 

and exists (select * from contrasena) and 100 > 

(select count(*) from information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1, 
information_schema T2)
```

The above query is mentioned in this paper :Time-Based Blind SQL Injection using Heavy Queries (Authors: Chema Alonso...)

I'm trying to make out the meaning of every piece of code, I do hope someone will help me.

1)Here's the URL:

http://www.kachakil.com/pista.aspx?id_pista=1

2) At this point I'm stucked (of course I know the meaning of select * from contrasena (probably contrasena is a 
table, so it means: select all records from the table contrasena)..but the rest? It's a subquery but I can't figure out the meaning

```
and exists (select * from contrasena) and 100 >
```

3) Here it's a select whose purpose is to count how many records the table called `columns`
 belonging to the database `information_schema` has. Also the table `columns` is renamed as `T1` and this what does it mean?: `information_schema T2`

I do apologize for my question...I do hope someone will help me..Thanks a lot

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start a query with `and`, so presumably this is part of a query. The syntax could be intended to mean prepend the SQL query from the link.

`exists (select * from contrasena)` is true if the table `contrasena` has any records.

`select count(*) from information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1, 
information_schema T2` is not valid syntax to my knowledge since `information_schema` is not a table.

I'll assume the above should be `select count(*) from information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1` instead. `tableA, tableB` means `tableA CROSS JOIN tableB`, thus a record is generated for each combination of records from `tableA` and `tableB`. `information_schema.columns` is a table with a record for each column (in each table) in the database, describing that column. So the subquery essentially return the square of the number of columns in the database. So:

```
100 > (select count(*) from ...)
=> 100 > DB_COL_COUNT^2 (not valid SQL)
=> 10^2 > DB_COL_COUNT^2 (not valid SQL)
=> 10 > DB_COL_COUNT (not valid SQL)
=> 10 > (select count(*) from information_schema.columns)
```

The first line is equivalent to the last in terms of meaning, but not execution time.

Thus `100 > ...` returns true if there are fewer than 10 rows in the database.

The `and`s in between simply mean that all the conditions must be true.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply..I made a mistake ..you're right what I wrote is  wrong ...I mean it should be information_schema. columns T2..Here's the link https://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-16/dc16-presentations/alonso-parada/defcon-16-alonso-parada-wp.pdf ..But I'd like to understand what's behind that..Sorry to bother you..

Comment: How did you make out that 100 > ... returns true if there are fewer than 10 rows in the database ?

Comment: @user1990170 This follows directly from the six lines preceding it (and the paragraph explanation before that). If it's supposed to be `information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1, information_schema.columns T2`, then the query returns (the number of columns)^3 and the check is for the cube root of 100, not the square root (10). But I suspect the 100 is just an arbitrarily chosen number. I think the point is just to give a server a lot of data to process without knowing anything about the table structures.

Comment: So summing up: 1st AND means there must be a table called contrasena if so let's count how many records there are 2nd AND means the number 100 is greater then what you get from the result of the "heavy query" (select count(*) from information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1, 
information_schema.columns T2) The heavy query in words: count the number of columns in the information:schema.columns table multiplied itself 3 times...Of course the AND operator requires TRUE in all cases...Am I correct?..Please point out my mistakes..Thanks again

Comment: Sorry again..One last question: but the result of the subquery (select count(*) from information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1, information_schema.columns T2) will never be less than 100, (my information_schema.columns has 537 records) so the 2nd AND will never be true..I'm unable to understand also how you can say that the check is for the cube root of the number of records you get from (select count(*) from information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns T1, information_schema.columns T2) ..I do apologize..thanks

Comment: It still needs to be evaluated to find that it's false, so whether it's true or false doesn't matter. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1, t2, t3` counts every combination of t1's rows with t2's rows with t3's rows. Thus the number of rows is rowCount(t1) x rowCount(t2) x rowCount(t3), thus cube. So similar to the equation in the answer, you'll have `100 > DB_COL_COUNT^3` -> ... -> `\3/100 > (select ...)`. It might help to [play around with this with a small table](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f489/11) to see what happens.